# EditText with numeric keyboard and comma

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to have EditTextPreference that accepts my pattern that consists of digits, comma and dash. My InputFilter works well with standard keyboard but I do not want standard but numeric keyboard. I can display it but only digits can be typed - dash and comma has no effect. How can I have numeric keyboard with digits, dash and comma? I tried all numeric* input types.

```
InputFilter[] filters = {new ValuesInputFilter()};
EditText editText = ((EditTextPreference) findPreference(KEY)).getEditText();
editText.setFilters(filters);

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="pref"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:summary="%s"
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InputType `phone` was the closest I could find when implementing something like this.

The fallback is to create your own numerical keyboard, it becomes quite simple as it's 10 buttons plus backspace/accept depending on your requirements. This is what I did when creating a pin entry screen for a banking application.

Comment: Hmm, I will postpone this enhancement to later polishing phase in this case.